# Mule: How to configure custom component factory?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want a custom factory to create my java component.
Is it possible in Mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring to instantiate your component from the custom factory and refer to the created bean with:

```
<component>
  <spring-object bean="yourBean"/>
<component>
```

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Spring+Beans+as+Flow+Components